# dns hosting - url forwarding - hiding forwarded url?

Tags: domains, redirects, dns, domain-forwarding

I have free dns hosting with the domain registrar and I'd like the dns hosted domain www.example.com to display contents of www.myotherlongdomain.com.

I only have 301/302/iframe forwarding options, however I want to mask the redirected (longdomain) url. If I use frames, users can view the source and see the (longdomain) url the contents are coming from.

How can I hide it so it always displays www.example.com?
There is no cloaking/masking option with the registrar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without being able to point www.example.com's DNS to www.myotherlongdomain.com, I'm afraid what you're asking is impossible. Without some kind of direct DNS control you won't be able to make www.example.com be equivalent to www.myotherlongdomain.com.

Since this is a limitation of the services you currently utilize, I'd recommend giving [ZoneEdit](http://www.zoneedit.com/) a try.

Comment: @Kevin Mark: it is already pointing via dns using frames, however i prefer not using a frame but also displaying www.example.com and not the long domain URL in the address bar, view source area, etc.

Comment: @jeremycollins: Frames are just HTML. So your site is really just pointing to another server that has a big frame in it that loads your www.myotherlongdomain.com site. I'm assuming you want to make www.example.com and www.myotherlongdomain.com to appear and work exactly the same.

Comment: @Kevin Mark: Exactly right. Users should be able to go to example.com, it then should not display the longdomain url anywhere, however display the contents of the longdomain.

Comment: @jeremycollins You will need to use a more advanced DNS service such as ZoneEdit for that. You need to point example.com to longdomain.com's IP and then configure the web server correctly to accept both domains.

Comment: @jeremycollins: You're very welcome.